# How To: Active State During Server Action w/o JavaScript

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, onion-architecture

On a page in the webapp I work on, users can select a file to upload and compose a message. When the user clicks "Send," I want the UI to reflect an active-state for the duration of the upload (not just as a pseudo-class for the clicking of the button)—either as the button being disabled with the dotted line around it, or a CSS-only animation. This could be a few seconds but is more likely to be several minutes, as the app works over the TOR Network, which is notoriously slow.

The webapp is hosted on an Onion service, and is accessed through the Tor Browser. It is a security-sensitive app, and as such can use ZERO javascript. At the beginning of the user flow, users are advised to have their Tor Browser block all Javascript—so any solutions that cite JS libraries or use embedded JS, will not work.

Also, I'm a designer—not a developer. My motivations for asking this question, are that user expectations HAVE to be managed better than they are, today—which is that the user hits the "Submit" button, and the page UI just does nothing; the only way a user can see anything is happening, is if they know to look at the browser's network activity, in its UI.

Because many of our users are not very technical, this is inadequate. Our dev team is phenomenal, but focused on security things—not so much UI/UX stuff. Hence, my request, here. :)

This hasn't been tackled yet. Posting here for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to give some indication using the `:focus` pseudo-class on the submit button (but that will, at best, last until the user clicks something else, not necessarily until the operation is complete).

Beyond that, you have to depend on the browser UI (e.g. the spinning icon in the tab for Chrome), subtle though it is.

[image: Browser UI]

Comment: I'm the UX designer on the project, and we're reserving `:focus` for keyboard nav & accessibility (it's intended use). Likewise, forcing users to identify browser cues is not adequate—and via this question, I'm hoping to learn of a way to achieve the goal in the UI itself. I appreciate the suggestion, though!

Comment: @ninavizz — And this answers that. There aren't any other options.